# How to load markers from MySQL using PHP and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I am new to Leaflet and I was wondering how to load markers from a MySQL database onto a leaflet map.

I don't want to only load the markers when the map is initialised but rather with a function because I would like the user to be able to, for example, select between dates and then load markers from those dates. I have done the following so far but I get an error:

```
leaflet.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var markerpositions;
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-55.7770641,55.6602758], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
    getlocations();
    var marker = L.marker(markerpositions).addTo(map);


function getlocations(){
var id = "1";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getlocationstomap.php",
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
    })
    .success(function(response) {
        if(!response.errors && response.result) {

            $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                markerpositions = '['+value[0]+','+value[1]+']';
           });


        } else {
            $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
            });
        }
    });
}
})
```

**PHP** (getlocationstomap.php)

```
<?php
// assign your post value
$inputvalues = $_POST;

// assign result vars
$errors = false;
$result = false;

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', "root", "", "traxi");

 /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    // escape your values
    foreach ($inputvalues as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $inputvalues[$key] = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $value );
        } else {
            $errors[$key] = 'The field '.$key.' is empty';
        }
    }

if( !$errors ) {
        // select your query
        $addresult = "
            SELECT `latitude`, `longitude` 
            FROM `positions` 
            WHERE `deviceid` = '" . $inputvalues['id'] . "'

         ";
//$returnResult = array();
         if( $result = $mysqli->query($addresult) ) {
            // collect results
            while($row = $result->fetch_all())
            {
                // assign to new array
                // make returnResult an array for multiple results
                $returnResult = $row;
            }
        }
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    // print result for ajax request
    echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);

    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you parse the ajax response, you are overwriting the variable `markerpositions` again and again, so only the last parsed variable will ever be added to the map.

Also the  `L.marker()` method needs an array as input, but your lat long data is assigned as a string in the variable `markerpositions` instead of an array.

Add your response data to the map like this:

```
$.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
    L.marker([ value[0], value[1] ]).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is answered and accepted but i thought i'de throw in another way (a way in which you'de never encounter the problem you ran into). When you have control over PHP and the output you're sending, i find it best to generate the data in GeoJSON format:

> GeoJSON is a format for encoding a variety of geographic data structures.

http://geojson.org/

It's easy to do and saves you a lot of hassle when using the data on the clientside and it's easily testable by using GeoJSON lint, something you can't easily do with a custom generated JSON structure. Also, GeoJSON can be used by virtually any GIS application out there, so your data is interchangable across a multitude of application.

You'll need to turn your MySQL rows into GeoJSON features, put them all in a GeoJSON collection, encode them to JSON and send them to the client. There you can load them at once into Leaflet's L.GeoJSON layer. An example in code:

Functions to generate a new/empty GeoJSON features and collections:

```
<?php

function createFeature () {
    $feature = new stdClass();
    $feature->type = 'Feature';
    $feature->properties = new stdClass();
    $feature->geometry = new stdClass();
    $feature->geometry->type = 'Point';
    $feature->geometry->coordinates = array();
    return $feature;
}

function createCollection () {
    $collection = new stdClass();
    $collection->type = 'FeatureCollection';
    $collection->features = array();
    return $collection;
}
```

Now when grabbing your rows from MySQL insert the data from each row into seperate features and push those features to a collection and send it to the client:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT name, latitude, longitude FROM locations";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    // Create a new collection
    $collection = createCollection();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

        // Create a new feature
        $feature = createFeature();

        // Add (optional) properties to the feature
        $feature->properties->name = $row->name;

        // Add coordinates to geometry coordinates array
        // Mind that GeoJSON works with lng/lat NOT lat/lng
        $feature->geometry->coordinates[] = $row->longitude;
        $feature->geometry->coordinates[] = $row->latitude;

        // Add the feature to the collection's features array
        $collection->features[] = $feature;
    }

    // Encode collection object to JSON and send to client
    echo json_encode($collection);

    $result->close();
}
```

You'll end up with an output similar to this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [1, 1]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Bar"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [2, 2]
        }
    }]
}
```

Now loading that into Leaflet is a breeze, `L.GeoJSON` will automaticly create `L.Marker`'s from GeoJSON point features:

```
// Grab the data via jQuery's getJSON
$.getJSON('url', function (collection) {

    // Create new GeoJSON layer with collection and add to map
    new L.GeoJSON(collection).addTo(map);
})
```

Using properties is very easy using `L.GeoJSON`'s `onEachFeature` method:

```
new L.GeoJSON(collection, {
    'onEachFeature': function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

That's it hope it might enlighten, here's some reference:

- L.GeoJSON reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson
- L.GeoJSON tutorial: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Comment: wow that seems like an ideal approach for me! thank you so much ! I shall definitely read up on it.